# Apache Redirect is redirecting all HTTP instead of just one subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

All HTTP requests, such as `http://example.com`, are getting redirected to `https://redmine.example.com`, but I only want `http://redmine.example.com` to be redirected.

I have the following in my `000-default` configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName redmine.example.com
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/redmine/public

        Redirect permanent / https://redmine.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        .
        .
        .
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my `default-ssl` configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName redmine.example.com
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/redmine/public

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

        <Directory /usr/share/redmine/public>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        LogLevel info
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/redmine-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        .
        .
        .
</VirtualHost>
```

**Is there anything here that is cause all HTTP requests to be redirected to `https://redmine.example.com`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `ServerName` in your second `<VirtualHost *:80>`; without that, no request will ever map to that virtual host.

If you want it to be the default for all requests that aren't to `redmine.example.com`, then put the redmine vhost below the default vhost in the file.

Comment: To clarify a bit further: apache will see the first vhost it encounters as the default vhost. So any request for a hostname not explicitely mentioned in a ServerName statement will be served by it. That's why Shane's swap advice is the right thing to do.